# How to open a file in command prompt located in a folder with a name that changes?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, discord

Okay, so I have a batch file I use to open a bunch of programs because it saves me time. The problem is Discord is stored in a folder with the version number in its name so every time Discord updates the name of the folder it is in goes from "app-0.0.303" to "app-0.0.304" to ect. So right now my code to open it is:

```
Start /d "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.304" Discord.exe
```

And next time it updates I will need to update the code to specify it is in app-0.0.305. So is there any way I can use like an "*" or something to say the folder could have any numbers at the end?

Comment: If you use the `cd` command to set the current directory first, "`app*`" will match the first (alphabetic) folder that starts with `app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just run a simple for loop:

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in ("%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Discord\app-*") do start "" /d "%%i" Discord.exe
```

Also look at the `%localappdata%` variable instead of `%userprofile%`, perhaps this is shorter?

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in ("%localappdata%\Discord\app-*") do start "" /d "%%i" Discord.exe
```

Comment: or `... do start "" /d "%%~dpi" Discord.exe` (to keep closer to the question - in case the .EXE needs to have this special working folder)

Comment: @Stephan thanks, maybe I will just change that yes...  but `%%~dpi` on the folder will do folder `discord`

Comment: Pleasure @wolf_